# Widget doesn't fill entire cell on tablet

Tags: android, layout, widget, cell, tablet

I have created a widget fallowing multiple tutorials but I am having a bit of a problem getting the widget to fill the entire cell.

When I load the widget on a smaller screen like my Samsung Galaxy S it fills the entire cell space, but on my tablet there seems to be large margins or padding around the widget layout that prevent it from filling the entire cell, but many of my other widgets I have downloaded fill the entire 2x2 cell area on my tablet.

Here is code I am using for the widget size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="146dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="146dp"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000" >

</appwidget-provider>
```

And the code for the widget layout itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout" android:background="@drawable/yellow">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried adding this into the manifest but it did not fix the problem

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

What am I missing that would cause my widget not to fill the entire cell area on a tablet?

[image: Screenshot of Widget Comparison]

Comment: What are the operating systems of the devices? Special considerations need to be made for devices running 4.0+.

Comment: yep. My galaxy S is android 2.2 but my tablet is 4.0. What is the special considerations I need to take into account?

Comment: The problem is outlined briefly [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy). A solution can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout). If this solves the issue, I'll post it in answer format for you.

Comment: Ok it states: "As of Android 4.0, app widgets are automatically given padding between the widget frame and the app widget's bounding box" I think this is the problem, I would like to get rid of the automatic padding that android 4.0+ adds, simply setting padding="0dp" only makes it so no additional padding is added, but does not remove the automatic padding. Great link though! =)

Comment: The automatic padding can't be removed, I'm afraid. That's part of the ICS design implementation. Sorry. =\

Comment: Then how do the other widgets I have fill the entire cell area on my 4.0 tablet?

Comment: They shouldn't be able to, unless you're getting more padding than I am envisioning. Can you show a screenshot comparison?

Comment: Ok updated with a screenshot. The other widget has quite a bit less padding on all sides compared to mine, especially from top to bottom

Comment: If you adjust `android:minHeight` and such, can you expand it to fill that area?

Comment: nah I tried that too. anything in the 2x2 range is the size of my widget. Even if I change the minHeight in both the appwidget-provider and the linearlayout

Comment: Then I'm afraid I'm out of ideas, sorry. :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! You just have to add

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

into the manifest. Anything below targetSdk of 14 will work though and allow you to use the full cell area since the automatic padding to widgets wasn't implemented until Android 4.0 - api 14.